# Can this C# method duplication be rewritten (Lambdas? Delegates?)?

Tags: c#, lambda, refactoring

Bear with me the world of lambdas, etc is making my head hurt.  I'm not even sure if the following code example is one where someone would use a lambda.

```
public static void AddDownloadMimeTypesToWebApps()
{
    var webApps = from svc in SPFarm.Local.Services.OfType<SPWebService>()
                  from SPWebApplication webApp in svc.WebApplications
                  where webApp.IsAdministrationWebApplication == false
                  select webApp;
    foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webApps)
    {
        foreach (FileExtensionData fed in MimeTypes)
        {
            webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add(fed.MimeType);
        }
        webApp.Update();
    }
}

public static void DeleteDownloadMimeTypesFromWebApps()
{
    var webApps = from svc in SPFarm.Local.Services.OfType<SPWebService>()
                  from SPWebApplication webApp in svc.WebApplications
                  where webApp.IsAdministrationWebApplication == false
                  select webApp;
    foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webApps)
    {
        foreach (FileExtensionData fed in MimeTypes)
        {
            webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Remove(fed.MimeType);
        }
        webApp.Update();
    }
}
```

Both methods are identical except for the Add() or Remove() calls.

Is there a way to refactor these that doesn't involve some strange reflection calls with passing in method names as strings, etc?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How bout something like this where we can make the unique code a lambda:

```
private static void DownloadMimeTypesToWebApps(Action<SPWebApplication,FileExtensionData> action)
{
    var webApps = from svc in SPFarm.Local.Services.OfType<SPWebService>()
              from SPWebApplication webApp in svc.WebApplications
              where webApp.IsAdministrationWebApplication == false
              select webApp;
    foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webApps)
    {
       foreach (FileExtensionData fed in MimeTypes)
       {
           action.Invoke(webApp,fed);
       }

       webApp.Update();
    }   

}

public static void AddDownloadMimeTypesToWebApps()
{
    DownloadMimeTypesToWebApps((webApp,fed) => webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add(fed.MimeType));
}

public static void DeleteDownloadMimeTypesToWebApps()
{
    DownloadMimeTypesToWebApps((webApp,fed) => webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Remove(fed.MimeType));        
}
```

Comment: @Christos 's answer is more true to how I would normally refactor.  I am marking this answer as correct because it aligns with the purpose of my original question.  I would like to ask as a follow-on... does it make a difference to someone as to which refactoring is preferable?  The lambda syntax or the one that Christos answered with, which before I had even heard of Lambdas would have been the way I would have gone?  Thanks in advance for any additional replies!  This has been very helpful in seeing the lambda.  My head still is trying to wrap around the way the parameters work. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3):

Initially, I would suggest you write a method to get the webApps:

```
public static IEnumerable<SPWebApplication> GetWebApps()
{
    var webApps = from svc in SPFarm.Local.Services.OfType<SPWebService>()
                  from SPWebApplication webApp in svc.WebApplications
                  where webApp.IsAdministrationWebApplication == false
                  select webApp;
    return webApps;   
}
```

Then, despite the fact that the rest of code is quite similar, since they do different things, I wouldn't join them to one method.

```
public static void AddDownloadMimeTypesToWebApps(IEnumerable<SPWebApplication> webApps)
{
    foreach (var webApp in webApps)
    {
        foreach (var fed in MimeTypes)
        {
            webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add(fed.MimeType);
        }
        webApp.Update();
    }
}
```

and

```
public static void DeleteDownloadMimeTypesFromWebApps(IEnumerable<SPWebApplication> webApps)
{
    foreach (var webApp in webApps)
    {
        foreach (var fed in MimeTypes)
        {
            webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Remove(fed.MimeType);
        }
        webApp.Update();
    }
}
```

Now you have three different methods with three different responsibilities. The first, `GetWebApps`, returns a sequence of the `WebApps`. The second adds download mime types to the web apps you pass as a parameter, `AddDownloadMimeTypesToWebApps` and the last one, `DeleteDownloadMimeTypesFromWebApps` delete them.

This way it is easy to remember what exactly does each method. Their purpose are crystal clear. Futhermore you don't hide from the consumer of the method what is needed as input. For instance, someone reads the name of the second method. The first question is which web apps? In the original code, where we don't pass the web apps as a parameter, we fetch them inside the mehtod's body. This is meaningless, since according to the name of the method we just want to add download mime types to some web apps and not to fetch them and then add the donwload mime types.

Last but not least since the retrieval of web apps is the same for both the cases of adding and deleting, we have to isolate this to one method that would serve exactly this. The last action not only enhances that mentioned above but it is also a clear appliance of the DRY principle, *don't repeat yourself*, which help us to write more maintainable code. Now if any time in the future you have to make some change in the retrieval of the web apps, you would have only one place, in which you have to look at, not two or more places.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I would actually normally do something to that affect.  I usually would call the extract WebApps code something like FilterWebApps().  Your refactoring is essentially identical to what I would normally write. :)  My interest was/is in learning more about lambdas and how to apply them into my code.  I feel like there's a rather important part of coding I am missing by not understanding lambdas/anonymous functions better.  Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

What about just a plain old parameter and if else?:

```
public static void EditMimeTypesToWebApps(int editType) // maybe you can make it an enum
{
    var webApps = from svc in SPFarm.Local.Services.OfType<SPWebService>()
                  from SPWebApplication webApp in svc.WebApplications
                  where webApp.IsAdministrationWebApplication == false
                  select webApp;
    foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webApps)
    {
        foreach (FileExtensionData fed in MimeTypes)
        {   
            if(editType == 0)
            {
                webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Remove(fed.MimeType);
            }
            else
            {
                webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add(fed.MimeType);
            }
        }
        webApp.Update();
    }
}
```

Easy enough to read. Easy enough for any level to maintain.

Comment: I have in the far past done methods like that, but I have come around to preferring that the method(s) be more singular in what it does.  It makes it more clear to know that calling a method called Delete* or Add* will (or at least should) do only that.  Thanks for your answer though.  I marked the example of the lambda as correct for what I am trying to learn about with my original question.  Again, thanks! Cheers :)

Comment: no problem just coined in my opinion. Everyone has their own style :-)